# Extend a Primitive only in current scope

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype, primitive

Is it possible to copy a primitive like `String` so it can be extended only in the current function?

```
var foo = function() {
    var String = // somehow clone String (the primitive function)
    String.prototype.first = function() { return this.charAt(0) };
    return 'abc'.first();
}
foo(); // returns 'a'
'abc'.first(); // returns TypeError "abc".first is not a function
```

The solution must either copy the primitive which doesn't seem possible, or destroy the new method after the function is complete...

Comment: You lose the readability benefit of using an extension method when you have to add in the highly error prone act of modifying a primitive type. Just use a local function.

Answer (score 3):

`String` is a global and if you change it or add to its prototype, then the changes are by definition global. So to revert the changes, you have to revert them.

Normally one would try to derive a custom subclass and add the new prototype method to it, but built-in types like String are notoriously hard to subclass, and even if you could you'd have to call it with something like `MyString('abc').first()`.

Your problems stem from your misguided notion of augmenting the `String` prototype. **It's never a good idea to pollute prototypes.** I understand your idea of dealing with that by somehow removing it real quick after adding it and using it, but that's not realistic, and the `setTimeout` approach is a horrible, unreliable hack.

However, if you really insist on adding to the `String` prototype, then one idea is to add all your new instance methods to a single property which is less likely to collide with things. Let's call it `Utils`. We would want to be able to call

```
'abc'.Utils.first()
```

But how can we make this work? We define a getter on the `Utils` property which returns a hash of the methods. Using a getter (instead of `value`) provides us with the `this`, which we can pass along to the methods using `bind`.

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'Utils', { 
  get: function() {
    return {
      first: function() { return this.charAt(0); }.bind(this)
    };
  }
});

> 'abc'.Utils.first()
< "a"
```

Comment: This is a very inelegant hack. In addition, how does this solve the OP's problem? You can still call `"abc".Utils.first()` outside of the `foo` function.

Comment: Missed your first cup of coffee this morning? I would not call this a "hack"; it's simply a way to group some prototype methods under a kind of namespace, so they are less likely to conflict with other things. Perhaps I did not state clearly enough that I was not trying to exactly implement what the OP claimed to want, since that is somewhere between impossible and inadvisable. I was answering the requirement that I sensed underlay the OP's question, which is to add to the `String` prototype in a somewhat safer way. If you don't like it, just downvote. Oh wait, you already did.

Comment: Okay, if you just want a namespace then how about `var Utils = { first: function (string) { return string.charAt(0); } };`? Why do you want to pollute `String.prototype` and make things more complicated than they need to be? In my humble opinion, using getters is an overkill. I understand that you sensed the OP's underlying problem (safely adding methods to a native prototype) and tried to address that. However, there's no need to. We already have a convention for that: don't add methods to native prototypes unless you are [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) a feature

Comment: I don't mind removing my downvote if you would just add a note stating that adding methods to native prototypes is highly discouraged.

Comment: @AaditMShah I will do that. I myself also am against polluting native prototypes.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to extend `String.prototype`? The easiest way is to just create a local function:

```js
alert(foo());        // "a"
alert(first("abc")); // ReferenceError: first is not defined

function foo() {
    return first("abc");

    function first(string) {
        return string.charAt(0);
    }
}
```

There's no advantage in using methods over functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.define = function(name, fn) {
    // Don't overwrite existing method
    if(String.prototype[name]) return false;

    // Make new method
    Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, name, {
        value: fn,
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: false,
        writable: false
    });

    // Delete method once parent function returns
    setTimeout(function() { 
        delete String.prototype[name] 
    }, 0);
}

var foo = function() {
    String.define('first', function() { 
        return this.charAt(0); 
    });
    return 'abc'.first();
}

foo(); // returns 'a'
'abc'.first(); // returns TypeError
```

This works by creating the method for String (the global) and deleting it only when the function containing it is complete. Effectively making it exist only in that scope. I don't know if asynchronous code executed in the time foo() is processing would have access to String.prototype.first but it would be interesting to test...

edit: Took a closer look and this doesn't work. the setTimeout that erases the prototype method only runs once the outermost parent function returns.
In this snippet, second call to '.first' works outside the function above it.

```
var foo = function() {
    console.log((function () {
        String.define('first', function() {
            return this.charAt(0);
        });
        return 'abc'.first();
    })());
    console.log('abc'.first())
}
```

Comment: By the way `configurable`, `enumerable` and `writable` all have suitable defaults and can be left unspecified.

Comment: This doesn't work as expected because `setTimeout` is not called immediately after the function `foo` returns: http://jsfiddle.net/oukvfm73/.

Comment: @AaditMShah why re-iterate what i already retracted in my own post?